# How do you count the number of tickets which are open at the beginning of the month in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have used the following code but it's not working (got wrong numbers)

```
Open Complaints at the beginning of month =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Incident),
    Filter(
      Incident,
      Incident[createdate] < RELATED( Calendar[MonthEnd])
    ),
    Filter(
      Incident,
      Incident[closedate] >= Related(Calendar[NextMonthstart]) || 
      ISBLANK(Incident[closedate])
    )
  )
```

Comment: Which columns is the relationship between `Incident` and `Calendar` tables on? Could you update your question with a screen shot of your data model of these two tables.

Comment: If a ticket is open on Feb 2nd, should it show for Feb? Or is it all open tickets before the start of the month (ie end of previous month). Trying to understand why `Calendar[MonthEnd]`.

Comment: No, not for Feb count. If it remains open until March first, then it will be counted for March.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Open Complaints at the beginning of month =
  var endOfPrevMonth = EOMONTH( MAX( Calendar[Date] ), -1)

  return
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS(Incident),
      REMOVEFILTERS(Calendar),
      Incident[createdate] <= endOfPrevMonth &&
      (
        Incident[closedate] > endOfPrevMonth ||
        ISBLANK(Incident[closedate])
      )
    )
```